# Javascript - Regex for double quotes on inch measurements

Tags: javascript, string

Given measurement data like:

> 2"
>
> 3" Contract

When coming back from the server it looks like this:

```
"\"2\"\"\""

"\"3\"\" Contract\""
```

e.g. as shown within the image:

[image]

I want the data to be displayed as a proper measurement to the user. So:

> 2"
>
> 3" Contract

As shown above

I resorted to complicated regexes to get the second example working (3" Contract) but it would just turn 2" to 2.

```
let measurement_formatted = value.replace("\"\"", '\"');
measurement_formatted = measurement_formatted.replace(/(^"|"$)/g, '');
measurement_formatted = measurement_formatted.replace("\"", '\"');
```

How can I develop a proper regex for both cases?

Comment: What is the problem and goal? Note `"\"\""` string literal is actually representing `""` text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, those `\` before the `"` are just put there to tell you that the `"` (preceded by a`\`) is being escaped.

Based on that, the string `"\"3\"\" Contract\""` is the same as `'"3"" Contract"'` because escaping `"` is no longer needed when the string is delimited by `'` character.

To answer, or rather land some help (which I'll always gladly do), you may use the following `regex` `/^"*|(\D)"/g` in conjunction with the `replace` method :

- `/` : tells the `JS` engine that we're creating a `regex`.
- `^"*` : tells the `JS` engine to match any `"` at the start of the string (0 or more).
- `|` : acts as the logical `OR` operator.
- `(\D)"` :

  - `(\D)` : creates a matching group of any NON-NUMERIC character.
  - `"` : the literal `"` character.
- `g` : tells the `JS` engine to match all the occurrences of that `regex`.

The idea here is to tell the `replace` method to replace all `"` characters that are preceded by a non-numeric character with that matched non-numeric character and entirely delete the `"` character.

Here's a live example :

```js
const regex = /^"*|(\D)"/g;

/** $1 : means write down the first matched capturing group */
console.log('"3"" Contract"'.replace(regex, '$1')); // 3" Contract

console.log('2"'.replace(/^"*|(\D)"/g, '$1')); // 2"
```

> Learn more about the [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

Hope i managed to land some help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and informative explanation

Comment: @Jebathon You're welcome! Glad I managed to help you.